# Is it possible to create a layer of honeypot for a network/system?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine

I would want to create a layer of honeypots to capture intruders who are willing to dig deeper into the honeypot while also having a email notifying system. The way its setup would be that they would be baited by this layer, and have to get through each and one of the honeypot. Within each attack or intrusion, the email notifier would alert us if anything has happened.

The layer of honeypots would consist of HoneyD, Kippo SSH or Dionaea. Ranging between Low and Medium interaction Honeypot.

Is it possible doing this? especially within VMware Workstations.

Sorry if my language or grammar is bad, English is my second language

Answer (score 0):

Yes ! It is possible but to accomplish that you should have distro(kalinux or parrot) for penetration test, which allow you to do that .
For more information look at http://www.kalinux.com and
http://www.parrot.com